# Best Practice for bulk removeEnd() edits

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice, string, performance

I have 35+ words that I need to search for within a string. If the string ENDS with any of the 35+ words then I need to remove them. I am using `.removeEnd()` and it works great. My issue is my method below only handles one word at a time and I feel like there has got to be a DRY way of writing this method to check for all 35+ words. Does anyone have any suggestions other then regex? I would like to continue to use APEX.

```
if (Trigger.new[0].Legal_Name_Normal__c.endsWith(' limited liability company')) {
    String replacement = 'limited liability company';
    newLegal = Trigger.new[0].Legal_Name_Normal__c.removeEnd(replacement); 
    Trigger.new[0].Legal_Name_Normal__c = newLegal;
}
```

My initial thought was to do an `OR` statement but if I did that, I am not sure how to target each item and save it into the `replacement` variable. My guess is I would have to save each word in its own String and then write a conditional around `newLegal = Trigger.new[0].Legal_Name_Normal__c.removeEnd(replacement);`

Does this seem like the best route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great use case for **`Regular Expressions`**. One benefit is you can make it case insensitive just by adding `(?i)` to the beginning of your expression.

```
List<String> substrings = new List<String>
{
    'limited liability company',
    'some other value',
    'etc.'
};
String expression = '(?i)(' + substrings.join('|') + ')$';
// this expression uses an or join to match any single expression
// followed by the end of the string

// without this terminating $, the expression would be equivalent to
// checking contains, rather than ends with

for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.Legal_Name_Normal__c != null)
    {
        record.Legal_Name_Normal__c = record.Legal_Name_Normal__c.replaceAll(expression, '');
    }
}
```

Comment: I normally love to quote Jamie Zawinski in situations involving regexp, but this really is one of the situations where a regexp is not only good, _it's the right tool for the job_.

Answer (score 5):

Use may choose to use String.replaceAll:

```
String keywordRegex = '(LLC|Inc\\.|Limited Liability Company|\\.com)$';
for( **SomeType** record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Legal_Name_Normal__c != null) {
        record.Legal_Name_Normal__c = record.Legal_Name_Normal__c.replaceAll(keywordRegex,'');
    }
}
```

This will perform a regex against any number of values (separated by the `|` for "OR" logic), and the "$" at the end matches only at the end of the string.

Comment: Haha, well that's near verbatim.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You know what they say about great minds, lol.

Comment: @sfdcfox and Adrian- great suggestions. I figured regex would be the easiest with this many records, I was just hoping for a way to do it with APEX methods. I didn't clearly explain the requirements, I just updated them. It is if the string ends with the word. which is why I chose `removeEnd()`. I am sure I can still specify this with regex.

Comment: Oh and I just read the end of your answer. You've got the end result covered! Thank you

Comment: @Olivia Yes, you could use removeEnd, but it's inefficient compared to a single replaceAll. You might want to take some time to learn how regex works, because it can turn really complicated logic into really simple logic.